# (DOORS/DXL)Update a DOORS module with info in other module

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm new to DXL Language.
That's my question: I'd like to update a DOORS module (MODULE A) by inserting (or update), in an *exact* point of the module tree, some rows that are in another DOORS module (MODULE B).

Infact I'd like to modify a *small* part of the entire module (MODULE A) in Excel, then import this part in a module (MODULE B) and then make the merge between the two modules.
Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: Now i use the import / export spreadsheet of DOORS :

Comment: Now I use the 'import / export spreadsheet' of DOORS : I export the entire module (MODULE A), modify it, then I import the modified MODULE A as spreadsheet. And it works. But I'd like to know if I can export the entire MODULE A, take a small part, modifiy it and import in a MODULE B, then import it in the entire MODULE A: with the 'import / export spreadsheet' of DOORS doesn't work. So it's possible to do with the DXL language?? thank you again

Comment: the approach how to place objects into Module B in DXL would be: for every object that is not in Module B, detect the predecessor and ancestor of this object in Module A, check whether these exist in Module B and if so, place the new object after/below the corresponding object in Module B. You will of course need your own object ID referencing system, as you cannot manipulate the Absolute Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a program is not done easily. We created a whole DXL commercial product with several years of development for the sole purpose of managing such branches:

- creating a branch (copy of the original module with references to the objects in the original module)
- comparing two modules (detecting changes in contents, detecting OLE changes, new objects, deletions, purge, changes in links, changes in structure (move up/down/left/right))
- merging changes from branches (applying the changes chosen by the user, taking over attribute content , adding objects at the exact point of the module tree, deleting objects, creating links etc., save merge action and continue later, finalize merge)

One of the problems you will face is how to do the 2nd merge (what has changed in the time frame after I applied the first changes from source to the destination module, which changes have been done in the source module, which changes have been done in the destination module, which changes need now to be applied to the destination module taking into consideration which changes have NOT been applied in the 1st merge), another will be the situation where you create branches of branches.

If you want to rewrite the same functionality in your own program instead of buying a solution, ensure that you have a good concept where you have a conceptual solution for every use case that will occur. This is not a DXL beginner's task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! You have been very concise.